# Article se queda por debajo de su contenedor padre

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy practicando con una web, y he creado un contenedor  y dentro de él he creado un  que contiene una imagen, un h4 y un parrafo. El problema está en que el section tiene 380px de altura, y el article se me baja hasta los 700px casi, como si hubiera un espaciado o un margin. Os dejo los codigos:

HTML

```
 <section>
            <article id="primero" class="articulos">
                <img src="img/icono1.png">
                <h4>LOREM IPSUM</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..</p>
            </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section{
    position:relative;
    top:560px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    display:block;
}


.articulos{
    clear:both;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%;
    top:0;

}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu código completo para que podamos ver el problema que estás teniendo?

Comment: en tu css mencionas a `.articulos`, pero en tu codigo HTML no está... ¿sería posibles que montaras el codigo en un CodePen o en jsfiddle?, así podemos ayudar mejor

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar:

```
position:relative
```

Esta propiedad significa que la posición será siendo dada por los contenidos/contenedores ya sean directos o indirectos, es decir, si tienes 3 divs, las alturas "no forzadas" (altura forzada: `height: 500px;` por ejemplo) se irán acomodando de forma *automática* .

Si estás usando esta propiedad, entendemos entonces que la propiedad *top* no debe existir, ya que esta propiedad será para posiciones *fixed* y posiciones *absolute* .

Tomando esta base en cuenta, debes eliminar estas propiedades de tu código, para que se acomoden de forma automática en orden y no te hagan posiciones extrañas (a menos que así lo quieras).

La segunda propiedad *extraña* que tienes se basa en `clear:both` que significa que limpiará los laterales, haciendo entonces, que si vas a posicionar 3 artículos, esto, no funcionará correctamente ya que los irá aventando debajo.

Si lo que quieres es hacerlo así deberías usar `float: left` como propiedad y el `inline-block` le podría dar cierto respaldo (aunque no sería del todo necesario).

Entonces tu primer clase pensando que se llama *.contenedor* quedaría:

```
.contenedor{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    display:block;
}
```

Y ya de ahí, sencillamente el section y article:

```
section{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    display:block;
    background:red;
}


article{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%;
    background:blue;

}
```

Quedando el HTML entonces:

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <section>
    <article>
      <!--- --->
    </article>
    <article>
      <!--- --->
    </article>
    <article>
      <!--- --->
    </article>
    <article>
      <!--- --->
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes un top de 560 px, lo cambie a 0px

article no se baja, prueba mi ejemplo y veras que no se baja

```css
section{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    display:block;
    background:red;
}


article{
    clear:both;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%;
    top:0;
    background:blue;

}
```

```html
<section>
            <article id="primero" class="articulos">
                <img src="img/icono1.png">
                <h4>LOREM IPSUM</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..</p>
            </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Si, está puesto asi porque arriba tiene otro contenedor de 560px, para que quede por debajo

Comment: @Jogofus no entiendo muy bien tu problema

Comment: @Jogofus debes añadir esa información en la misma pregunta y añadir un [mcve] a la misma.

Comment: @Jogofus edite mi respuesta, revisalo porfavor